# Failed Triage audit -- The OP's changed name caused sock puppet suspicion

Tags: feature-request

I just flagged a triage question for moderator attention, because I noticed that the clarifying comments in the question were coming from a different account than the OP -- suggesting to me possible sock puppet.  But, apparently the question asker had been changed *for the purpose of the audit*... Had the account been the same in the question and coments I wouldn't have suspected sock puppets, I would have passed the audit :)  I'm not sure if you can see the message I used for the flag in an audit, but here's the link to that audit:  https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/6839250

I don't really care about the failed audit, but suggest that if we're "changing the name to protect the innocent" on the audit questions, change it in the comments too.

Comment: I think it's fair to say that sock puppet detection is not the purpose of the Triage queue.  Focus on the post, not the user.

Answer (score 5):

The Triage review queue does not exist for you to review whether an account is suspicious or an user's integrity. You are reviewing a post and whether or not it is suitable for the site.

If you think the author of the post is questionable, complete the review normally and then do more investigation or flag for moderators **outside** of review. That button is labelled "**Unsalvageable**" - not "flag for moderators."

Comment: That's true. But with seasoned eyes, I admit I'm also finding it _really difficult_ to think of posts in the triage queue in that limited context -- to the extent that I even got myself an audit ban this week for acting above & beyond, or too aggressively. I've come to treat nearly every triage review with suspicion, and open the questions in new tabs.  Seems like audits used to be just really obvious spam and nasty stuff, but maybe I'm misremembering.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Audits take different forms in different queues.